# Use middle server ip address to connect main openvpn server

Tags: networking, server, openvpn

My main server ip address that i installed openvpn server on, is blocked in my country.
that means i cant connect to openvpn directly. so I bought another server. i want to use this second server to connect my main openvpn. every methods that is fast is fine for me.

both servers are ubunutu 20.04

Comment: How will a second machine have any more chance of working? What is different about it?

Comment: @David i change the second server when its blocked but i need to connect the main server at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use iptables for port forwarding
The CLI Syntax looks like

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <PORT> -j DNAT --to-destination <main-Server-IP>
```

check man page for details.

You should install the packages `iptables` and `iptables-persistent`.
For a persistent configuration (load at reboot) you need to save your configuration with

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

I guess your 2nd server does have "only” one interface. IP-Forwarding must be enabled.
Add the line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

to

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

A reboot is needed.

Iptables is a very powerful tool - be careful. If you misconfigure if you may lose access to the server.

Comment: actually i tried this method. this is tcp. but i tried both but not working.

Comment: for udp you may use `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport <PORT> -j DNAT --to-destination <main-Server-IP>` check the man page ...

Comment: yes i did it worked i think